# Converting 16 bit unsigned int array to 32 bit float array

Tags: c++, type-conversion, directx-9

I am using directx 9 with 64bit render targets...I need to read the data on the render target surfaces. Each color component( a,r,g,b ) is encoded with 2 bytes( or 16bits x 4 = 64 ). How do I convert each 16 bit color component to a 32 bit floating point variable? Here is what I've tried:

```
BYTE *pData = ( BYTE* )renderTargetData;

for( UINT y = 0; y < Height; ++y )
{

   for( UINT x = 0; x < width; ++x )
   {
       // declare 4component vector to hold 4 floats
       D3DXVECTOR4 vColor;

       // convert the pixel color from 16 to 32 bits
       D3DXFloat16To32Array( ( FLOAT* )&vColor, ( D3DXFLOAT16* )&pData[ y + 8 * x ], 4 );
    }
}
```

For some reason this is incorrect...In one case after conversion, where the actual renderTargetData for one pixel is ( 0, 0, 0, 65535 ), I get this result: ( 0, 0, 0, -131008.00 ).

Comment: Is it 16 bits of integer data, or 16 bits of floating point data?

Comment: And I take it you want a float value between 0..1.0?

Comment: 16bits of floating point data...and yes it should be within 0 to 1.0f

Comment: Well, then your input should not be 0,0,0,65535 - in fact, 65535 can't be expressed as a FP16...

Comment: input is 2 bytes per color component...sorry...not a FP16...each render target pixel has 16 bits per channel( color component ) the format is: A16B16G16R16 ... so 65535 is the greatest value that this render target can have( 2^16 different values - 0 -> 65535 )

Comment: i see now your point though I'm using the wrong function...how can I convert a WORD to a floating point variable?

Comment: Well, then you shouldn't be using `D3DXFloat16To32Array`, since that is translating FP16 to FP32.

Comment: I can convert the WORD to DWORD first and divide by 2^32 can't I?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Don't do DirectX (I work with OpenCL, and have recently done some work on FP16, which is something I just started writing an answer for - but since that's NOT what you want, it's a bit of a waste of time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, converting an integer `v` from integer in range `[0..n]` to float in range `[0.0..1.0]` is:

```
float f = v/(float)n;
```

So, in your case, a loop that does:

```
vColor.x = (pData[ y + 4 * x ])/65535.0f; 
vColor.y = (pData[ y + 4 * x + 1 ])/65535.0f; 
// ... etc.
```

should work, if we change the `BYTE *pData = ( BYTE* )renderTargetData;` into `WORD *pData = ( WORD* )renderTargetData;`

But there may be some clever way for DX to do this for you that I don't know of since I